# Customized Listview with items containing Checkboxs when Scrolling the List

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, scroll

I have a problem with my customized Listview with 2 TextViews and a CheckBox in each item, the problme is when scrolling the Listview, the checked items get unchecked randomly and vice versa, can anyone help to define a customized Adapter to solve this problem, i'll be so thankful

Comment: There are hundreds of question on stackoverflow.com regarding this issue, many with full code, and you didn't manage to find a single one?

Comment: you need to manage your ChecBox Click in one ArrayList Like in this example which used for seekBar hope you will find solution.http://android-vogue.blogspot.com/2012/05/android-custom-listview-with-seekbar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved as follows:

I have a boolean variable **isCheckedByUser**. In the adapter, everytime I do something with the checkbox, i set this variable to false first, do all the things I have to with the checkbox, and set the variable to true again. Then, in the method **onCheckedChanged** I check if this variable is true, if so, means that the user wanted to modify the state, so I do whatever its needed with the checkbox.

In fact, this problem is not so "random". The listview reuses the cells, so that's why for you seems like the checkboxes are unchecked randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you correctly recycle the `convertView` param in `getView`.

If the view was already in use, ensure the checked state fits with the new item represented.